# Yank command not found

Tags: rubygems

I am using RubyGems version 1.3.7. I just pushed a bad gem to the server, and now want to remove it using the `gem yank` command, which is what the instructions on the terminal tell me to do. Yet when I run this, I get command not found errors.

So did the command get removed? What can I do to push a gem up to RubyGems without building a new version?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Install gemcutter--it will add global `yank` and `webhook` commands for rubygems.

`# gem install gemcutter`

And you **can't** push the same gem version twice. Yanking just marks a particular version as 'invalid'.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and here is how to remove the gem from *gemcutter.org*

You probably have to install the **gemcutter version >= 0.5.0**

After You have done that just do `yank` on the gem eg. `gem yank gem_name -v VERSION_HERE`

If you want to undo the `yank` use `gem yank gem_name -v VERSION_HERE --undo`